# how to change default Bootstrap link hover color to custom color?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to change default Bootstrap link hover color to custom color?

It seems that the chrome inspector (DOM) does not take my CSS code (even with the !important). How can I make my code be used when uploading my site to the web?

This is my CSS:

```
a {
    color: hsla(34,55%,54%,1);
}

footer > a: hover {
    color: hsla(151,27%,56%,1) !important;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<footer class="col-sm-12">
            <address>
                <a href="privacy-policy.html">Privacy Policy</a>  | © 2014 Colostomo | <a href="about.html">About This Site</a> <br> Colostomo • 1000 Main Street • Marshall, MO 65340 • 660-555-1212
            </address>
        </footer>
```

Comment: `footer > a: hover` there should be no space between `a:` and `hover`. It should be. `footer > a:hover `

Comment: **This is a typo. Please close this instead of answering.** `:)`

Comment: it is typo mistake. It should be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  **footer > address >a:hover** instead of  **footer > a: hover**,because footer didn't have a child a.

```css
a {
    color: hsla(34,55%,54%,1);
  
}

footer > address >a:hover {
    color: hsla(151,27%,56%,1) !important;

}
```

```html
<footer class="col-sm-12">
            <address>
                <a href="privacy-policy.html">Privacy Policy</a>  | © 2014 Colostomo | <a href="about.html">About This Site</a> <br> Colostomo • 1000 Main Street • Marshall, MO 65340 • 660-555-1212
            </address>
        </footer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will make these changes :)

Comment: Or `footer a:hover {}`.